# Create GSI on an attribute which has the value of Set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamo-local

So i want to create a simple Dynamodb table called reminders which at the moment has 3 columns :

1. `reminder_id` : This is the hash key
2. `reminder_tag`: I want to have a global secondary index on this field . But at the same time i want to ensure that the tags attribute should have the datatype of Set . Because there can be multiple tags on a reminder.
3. `reminder_title`: I also want to have a global secondary index on this field. This will be a string field.

I checked the documentation : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#valid-dynamodb-types on what are the possible datatypes available in Boto3 .

So i have come up with this script :

```
import boto3


def create_reminders_table():
    """Just create the reminders table."""
    session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dynamo_local')
    dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
    table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName='Reminders',
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'reminder_id',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'
            }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'reminder_id',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'reminder_tag',
                'AttributeType': 'SS'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'reminder_title',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            }
        ],
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
            {
                'IndexName': 'ReminderTagGsi',
                'KeySchema': [
                    {
                        'AttributeName': 'reminder_tag',
                        'KeyType': 'HASH'
                    }
                ],
                'Projection': {
                    'ProjectionType': 'INCLUDE',
                    'NonKeyAttributes': [
                        'reminder_title'
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                'IndexName': 'ReminderTitleGsi',
                'KeySchema': [
                    {
                        'AttributeName': 'reminder_title',
                        'KeyType': 'HASH'
                    }
                ],
                'Projection': {
                    'ProjectionType': 'KEYS_ONLY'
                }
            }
        ],
        BillingMode='PAY_PER_REQUEST'
    )
    return table


if __name__ == '__main__':
    movie_table = create_reminders_table()
    print("Table status:", movie_table.table_status)
```

But when i run this i get the below issue:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable operation: Member must satisfy enum value set: [B, N, S]
```

I searched and came across this question asked by someone which has the same issue : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=613970

Can someone please help me with this since the solution of not providing a datatype either does not work .

Also is it possible to have an index on a an attribute which is of value Set ? I mean i should enable the user to search for reminders with a tag , and for doing that i need to have a set.

Request someone to please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have an index on an attribute which is of value Set ?

No. As the [CreateTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-KeySchema) docs say, "the attributes in KeySchema must also be defined in the AttributeDefinitions", to a data type to one of (S)tring, (N)umber or (B)inary."

> enable the user to search for reminders with a tag , and for doing that i need to have a set.

A DynamoDB workaround for one-many relations is a [composite sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html) as in `urgent#work`. That would only be sensible for a small, fixed number of tags, though.

Your least-bad option is to query by user (and perhaps further narrowing with some sort key), then filtering the results by tag membership outside DynamoDB. (N.B. The `IN` operator cannot be used in a Query's [FilterConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions), so it's of no use to you here).

> I want to have a global secondary index on `reminder_title`

`reminder_title` is a poor candidate for an index Primary Key.  An index's (and table's) `Primary Key` must ensure per-record uniqueness. A title would likely not.  You probably need a combination of 3 elements, `user_id`, `request_id` and `title`, to ensure key uniqueness across records.

Consider a [composite Primery Key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) with, say, `user_id` for the `Partition Key` (= `HASH`) and a [compound sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html) in a new column (`SK`) that concatenates `title#request_id`.  You would then search by-user-by-title with:

```sh
user_id="Zaphod" AND begins_with(SK, "exercise")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation !! It really helps :)

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html

“Each primary key attribute must be a scalar (meaning that it can hold only a single value). The only data types allowed for primary key attributes are string, number, or binary. There are no such restrictions for other, non-key attributes.”